# Unable to connect to WCF server port

Tags: windows, wcf, tcp, port, block

I created a WCF service and deployed it to my production environment (Windows 2008). The client (also Windows 2008) cannot connect to the server port. I have stopped the Windows Firewall service on the server, and I can see the port listening when I use netstat from command line on the server. I am fairly sure that it is a problem related to the port because I can ping the server, but when I tried to do telnet serverIP port, I got an error. The client machine can connect to other machines on the network (e.g. DB server) so it does not seem to be a problem on the client side. Any ideas on what else could cause the port to be blocked?

Thanks

Comment: Are the server & client on the same LAN segment or are other machines in-between? Is it possible to connect from the server machine (e.g. with WcfTestClient.exe)? What kind of response do you get after you try to open the service address in the browser on the client/on the server? When using telnet, do you get an instant error, or is there a timeout? Is any antivirus software on the server running?

Comment: The client and server are on the same LAN segment. I can connect to the windows service from a different machine on the same LAN, but not from where my client is hosted. When using telnet, there is a timeout after a short (< 30 secs) interval.